# 'could not decode' errors logged when accessing Experience Analytics dashboard

Tags: experience-analytics

When accessing Experience analytics dashboard, I'm seeing a lot of 'could not decode' errors generated in the logs. How can I identify what is missing from the logged values ?

> 15608 17:16:07 INFO 
>   [Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger] [Experience
>   Analytics]: Request: /sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/3C5C3FD36C9C4A30B43C71341E81BABF/-7086413679876148633,-7734637993024985948,8416260180981822611?&dateGrouping=collapsed&&keyOrderBy=count-Desc&dateFrom=06-11-2017&dateTo=06-11-2018&keyGrouping=by-key
>   returned messages.
>
> 1732 17:16:07 WARN 
>   [Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger] [Experience
>   Analytics]: Could not decode '3037769370418898760'
>
> 1732 17:16:07 WARN 
>   [Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger] [Experience
>   Analytics]: Could not decode '-811654643043498697'
>
> 1732 17:16:08 WARN 
>   [Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger] [Experience
>   Analytics]: Could not decode '2750502006984993720'